# this traitLogout function within laravel LoginController

Tags: php, laravel

I have this `return $this->traitLogout($request)` line within the LoginController of a project I got pushed to take over.  But as I do not shy away from work I am giving it my all.  Even though I enjoy php I have spent little time with a template system such as laravel.  
So I know the path to the `AuthenticatesUser` class which contains a logout function but did not expect to find, after I echoed out an empty function of the LoginController object `$this->traitLogin()`, to point to the same `AuthenticatesUser` logout function.
So what is `traitLogout()`, how is it acting as a sort of clone or shortcut function to another function and where is it made within the project directory?  
The reason I am asking is I noticed that if a session expires and a user clicks logout, they get a session expire message which tells them to refresh and try again.  But refreshing does not redirect as intended by the pre-programmed function, they are caught on that page.

```
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
 
        $request->session()->invalidate();
 
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php and look at the conflict resolution sections. At the top of your class there is probably a use statement with defined the `traitLogout` function. This basically allows developers to rename a trait method, define their own method with the same name, and still be able to call the original trait method. Bit like overriding methods from inherited classes, but now in the context of traits.

Comment: O yes, I se now it was redefined as `use AuthenticatesUsers {
      logout as protected traitLogout;}`.  Thanks,  that put me on the right track.